# Redirects issue in ngrinder groovy-Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, performance, groovy, grinder, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am facing an issue when I am scripting the redirects in nGrinder (Script written in Groovy in Eclipse; Eclipse integrated with Groovy plugin) for the URL: https://winterfell-sbo-sbo-test-cso-web-mta.cfapps.sap.hana.ondemand.com/sites
 Attached is the Eclipse log (Page #11, #12, #13) for your reference and below is the explanation on the issue.

Step#1
 I fire a HTTP GET request on https://winterfell-sbo-sbo-test-cso-web-mta.cfapps.sap.hana.ondemand.com/sites.
 This automatically follows redirects and then lands on to the Login Page: https://winterfell.authentication.sap.hana.ondemand.com/login

Step#2
 I fire another HTTP GET request on 'https://winterfell.authentication.sap.hana.ondemand.com/saml/discovery?returnIDParam=idp&entityID=winterfell.canary&idp=winterfell-metadata&isPassive=true
 This doesn't automatically redirect to "Location" header -> https://winterfell.authentication.sap.hana.ondemand.com/saml/login/alias/winterfell.canary?disco=true&idp=xs2security.accounts400.ondemand.com

Refer to the screenshot for more information.

Instead it gets redirected to https://winterfell.authentication.sap.hana.ondemand.com/login
 We tried to capture and set the csrf cookie for the GET request of https://authentication.sap.hana.ondemand.com/saml/discovery?returnIDParam=idp&entityID=winterfell.canary&idp=winterfell-metadata&isPassive=true -> but still it isn't working as expected

Colleague was able to make this work in JMeter. So we are trying to simulate this in nGrinder by setting "followRedirects" to true and it isn't working as expected.

Since in Step#2, it is not picking up the location of the response header and redirecting back to "/login" page, what could be the possible reasons for this behavior?

we checked if xsuaa is working fine. On executing the request in Postman, everything worked as expected. Curl works well.